# Why can't I use the present LUN approach for system dbs?

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-2019

I'm planning to move sql server to new hardware, same version.

On the RHS, it is mentioned that script in system objects. Why can't I use the present LUN approach for system dbs?

[image]

Comment: Its risky and IIRC it is not a supported means to move system database.

Comment: Probably the diagram doesn't say attach LUN for system db as it is assuming an upgrade, rather than same version migration? Any reference to you above comment please?

Comment: For system DB's please dont attach, please use restore, I can say that with high level of confidence.

Comment: Can you give any reference why not to attach system db when target sql version is the same? Technically this is how fci works during failover.

Comment: If you're going to try to do this by migrating LUNs, the new server must EXACTLY match the old one....drive letters, SQL version, patch levels, file level permissions, etc.  It would be much less risky to just use a native SQL backup/restore and scripts.